# how do i find the occurrence and percentage of occurance of a word in a string ; how to fix error

Tags: python, counter, find-occurrences

basically i have this excel file that i uploaded to python, i made a new column which identified if a word was in each row and if it was in a row then it would come out as true, if not false. So i have this new column and im trying to find the percentage of true and false. Later i will try to make a table separating all the ones that are true and false. I need help with the percentage one first. I am a beginner like i started this last week

so for the percentage problem i decided to first create a code to count the occurrence of the word "true" and "false" in the column and then i would have just did some math to get the percentages but i didn't get past counting the occurrence. The product of the codes below were 0 and thats not what is suppose to display.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\New folder\CrohnsD.xlsx')
print (df)
df['has_word_icd'] = df.apply(lambda row: True if 
row.str.contains('ICD').any() else False, axis=1)
print(df['has_word_icd'])
#df.to_excel(r'C:\New folder\done.xlsx')
test_str = "df['has_word_icd']"
counter = test_str.count('true')
print (str(counter))
```

this is the updated version and it still gives me 0, i cannot change df['has_word_icd'] because thats how the variable is introduced initially

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\New folder\CrohnsD.xlsx')
print (df)
df['has_word_icd'] = df.apply(lambda row: True if 
row.str.contains('ICD').any() else False, axis=1)
print(df['has_word_icd'])
#df.to_excel(r'C:\New folder\done.xlsx')

test_str = (df['has_word_icd'])

count = 0
for i in range(len(test_str)):
   if test_str[i] == 'true':
        count += 1
  i += 1

print(count)
```

both gave me the same result

please help me, the output from both codes is "0" and it shouldn't be that. Somebody help me get a code that just directly gives me the percent of the "true" & "false"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using a list comprehension. For the percentage, you can use the `np.mean()` function:

```
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['hello icd', 'bob', 'bob icd', 'hello'],
                  'b' : ['bye', 'you', 'bob is icd better', 'bob is young']})

df['contains_word_icd'] = df.apply(lambda row :
                                   any([True if 'icd' in row[x] else False for x in df.columns]), axis=1)
percentage = np.mean(df['contains_word_icd'])
# 0.5
```

---

Output :

```
           a                  b  contains_word_icd
0  hello icd                bye               True
1        bob                you              False
2    bob icd  bob is icd better               True
3      hello       bob is young              False
```

Comment: thanks but that wasn't what i was asking, i already did that code. i have that as part of my question. Im asking for a way to count the percentage of trues & false. thanks though

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, I updated it to count the percentage of each column of each row to contain teh word icd

Comment: But do you want this percentage or a global percentage showing the percentage of any row to contain the word icd ?

Comment: i have a column that tell me if the row contains the word "icd" or not. so if the row contains icd it has the word "true" but if it does not then it has "false". the name of that column is called "has_word_icd". Now im trying to which percent of the column is "true' and "false" only for the "has_word_icd" column

Comment: You could use `np.mean(df['contains_word_icd'])` to get the percentage of True.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem lies here: `"df['has_word_icd']"`. You put a variable in quotes which to python means its a plain string. Correct would be 
`test_str = df[has_word_icd]`

Then you loop through the `test_str` like so:

```
count  = 0
for i in range(len(test_str)):
  if test_str[i] == 'true':
        count += 1
  i += 1

print(count)
```

Then get the percentage:

`percent =  (count  / range(len(df[has_word_icd]]) * 100`

Comment: thanks for you effort but it is just printig a bunch of zeros once i do print(count)

Comment: @mixjr365cool I amended my answer to fix to capitalisation errors. Should work fine now, did a quick test run on a csv based df and it worked fine for me

Comment: i still get the same result of zero. i don't know why, look at the code, i updated it

Comment: what's the output if you print `df['has_word_icd']`? Does it correctly ouput your True & False values? I couldn't replicate the error...